# Default http client alternatives and optimization

Tags: php, android, json, listview, http-get

Im using the default http client currently for sending a httpget call to my php script which recieves data from a mysql server and consequemtly there's the job of json parsing and more.

1. I load more items into a listview using the above ..etc. should i close my http client after every call or can i leave it open ?
2. Is there a more optimized alternative , i've looked up retrofit and volley but i am not sure.
3. Is there a way i can optimize this whole operation without alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query). Just give it a try. It is so easy to use and it works just fine for me.

It is used as follows:

```
Aquery aq = new AQuery(context);
aq.ajax(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit), which I've used on several projects to make HTTP requests. You could also use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) if you wanted. There are many other options available too.

> My point is that **most of the time a library (like Retrofit) is much better than writing it yourself**. This is because they have spent countless hours developing it and are most likely experts in that area. If you want something custom then go ahead, but for anything else i'd use a library in this case. You don't have to worry about things like closing HTTP clients. You also have the benefit of **less code to write and less bugs that could be introduced** into your code base.

With Retrofit you create an interface defining all of the endpoints you wish to call. You also create [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)'s to hold the data that comes back. You call Retrofit's generated method and it makes the request, parses the JSON and fills your POJO's with data. Then you can then feed these objects into your listview.

---

> #### Futher Reading
>
> 1. The official [Retrofit guide](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for information on how to implement it in your project.
> 2. [Jake Wharton's blog post about Retrofit](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/retrofit-one-dot-oh.html) on Square's Engineering Blog
> 3. [Another tutorial on Retrofit](http://www.ishankhanna.in/blog/android-development/retrofit-tutorial-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer , a little help like a tutorial would be good to top it off.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some more tutorials - enjoy!

Comment: May chuck Norris be with you ;) thank you !